# Use both multiple sets of footnotes and multiple columns at once

Tags: footnotes

I have read a number of threads regarding solutions to 1) how to use multiple sets of footnotes and 2) how to have multiple columns in footnotes.

However, I am having difficulty mixing the two. For example, manyfoot or bigfoot can handle multiple sets of footnotes, but not multiple columns. The memoir class or the dblfnote package can handle multiple columns, but I am not sure how to get them to work well with multiple sets.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

- Two sets of footnotes
- The first set should be in two columns
- The second set should be in a single column as normal
- Footnote content should not wrap beneath the footnote mark on the second line, but be separated from the mark by whitespace

Here is a minimal example using the memoir class and manyfoot (bigfoot seems to automatically cancel the multicolumn feature of memoir):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\twocolumnfootnotes

\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{1em}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1.\hfill}

\usepackage{manyfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[roman]

\begin{document}

This is some\footnote{This is a first footnote, which should be extra long in order to demonstrate long footnotes in the different configurations.} sample\footnoteA{This is a first footnote.} text\footnoteA{This is a first footnote.} containing\footnote{This is a second footnote.} a number\footnoteA{This is a second footnote.} of footnotes, allowing one to demonstrate\footnote{This is a third footnote.} the behaviour of different\footnote{This is a fourth footnote.} footnote configurations.

\end{document}
```

This is what the two sets of footnotes look like. Notice that:

1. The default footnotes are typeset below the ones defined with manyfoot.
2. The desired behaviour for the footnote marks and text is not achieved in the first long footnote.

[image]

If instead, the `\twocolumnfootnotes` command is ommitted, the result is quite different. Notice that:

1. The default footnotes are typeset before the ones defined by manyfoot.
2. The desired behaviour is achieved regarding the footnote mark and text in the first long footnote.

[image]

How can I achieve all the behaviour I am looking for with the double column set of footnotes first, followed by a second set of footnotes in one column, and with the indentation of the footnote text starting at the second line?

Answer (score 0):

All of the desired behaviour can be achieved using the [reledmac](https://ctan.org/pkg/reledmac?lang=en) package. The following MWE produces the result shown below:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{reledmac}

%% Footnote set A: two columns %%
% \renewcommand*{\normalfootfootmarkX}... affects footnote set B as well
\arrangementX[A]{twocol}
\renewcommand*{\normalfootfootmarkX}[1]{%
  \hbox to 1.25em{\hfill\textnormal{\arabic{footnoteA}.\hspace{2pt}}}%
}
\hangindentX{1.35em}

%% Footnote set B: single column %%
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteB}{\roman{footnoteB}}
\renewcommand*{\footfootmarkB}{%
    \hbox to 1.25 em{\hfill\textnormal{\roman{footnoteB}.\hspace{2pt}}}}

\begin{document}

This is some\footnoteA{This is a first footnote, which should be extra long in order to demonstrate long footnotes in the different configurations.} sample\footnoteB{This is a first footnote, which should be extra long in order to demonstrate long footnotes in the different configurations.} text\footnoteB{This is a second footnote.} containing\footnoteA{This is a second footnote.} a number\footnoteB{This is a third footnote.} of footnotes, allowing one to demonstrate\footnoteA{This is a third footnote.} the behaviour of different\footnoteA{This is a fourth footnote.}\footnoteB{This is a fourth footnote.} footnote configurations.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The reledmac package also allows one to customize the order in which footnote sets appear on the page if desired.

Comment: It looks like `\hangindentX{1.3em}` produces a superior result (rather than 1.35em).